# Dealing with nested classes in Scala

Tags: scala, class, nested

I am unable to understand how to work with nested classes in Scala esp when I encountered the error below:

```
class Action {
  val entityModelVar = new EntityModel
}

class EntityModel {
  class EntityLabel {
   ....
   }
}
```

The above code-snippet gives an idea about my class structure. Here's two code blocks that puzzle me on how they work.

```
val actionList=Array[Action](Action1,Action2)
..
val newLabels=actionList(i).test(doc)
actionList(i).retrain(newLabels) //error pointed here

**Error: type mismatch:
found   : Seq[a.entityModelVar.EntityLabel]
required   : Seq[_13.entityModelVar.EntityLabel] where _13:Action**
```

However, the following code compiles without any error:

```
//This works fine
val a=actionList(i)
val newLabels=a.test(doc2)
a.retrain(newLabels)
```

Also, here is the definition of the `retrain` function:

```
 def retrain(labels:Seq[entityModelVar.EntityLabel])={
   entityModelVar.retrain(labels)
 }
```

and the signature of `EntityModel.retrain` function:

```
def retrain(testLabels:Seq[EntityLabel]):Unit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the inner class has got to belong to the same *instance* of the outer class.  But is `actionList(i)` guaranteed to be the same instance between two calls?  The compiler doesn't know for certain (maybe another thread fiddles with it? who knows what `apply` does anyway?), so it complains.  The `_13` is its name for a temporary variable that it wishes were there to assure that it *is* the same instance.

Your next one works because the compiler can see that you call `actionList(i)` once, store that instance, get an inner class from it and then apply it.

So, moral of the story is: you need to make it abundantly obvious to the compiler that your inner class instances match up to their proper outer class, and the best way to do that is to store that outer class in a val where it can't change without you (or the compiler) noticing.

(You can also specify types of individual variables if you break up parameter blocks.  So, for instance: `def foo(m: EntityModel)(l: m.EntityLabel)` would be a way to write a function that takes an outer class an an inner one corresponding to it.)

Comment: This requirement looks to be very rigid, imagine maintaining the same instance across different files. It would simply not be possible as I would be passing this instance in a function to the file that needs it but since it would not get the same instance (it gets the argument value), the compiler won't be "guaranteed". Is there a way to defer the type check till runtime?

Comment: @arbazkhan002 - Well, you can always just declare that you know better than the compiler what you're doing by casting `l.asInstanceOf[m.EntityLabel]`, but there's no guarantee that you'll even get a runtime error if you mess up with that.